# Case query based on two input values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, sql-like

I have two tables (`fruits` and `fruitSales`), where my query requirement is:

```
if fruit = 'Apple' OR 'Banana' then fire (query1) else fire(query2)
```

// i.e.., when my input is apple or banana, then query1 has to fire or else query2.

Here are my two queries:

Query #1:

```
 select a.*, b.quantity 
 from fruits a 
 left join fruitSales b on a.fruitPrice = '%'+b.fruitPrice+'%' 
 where a.fruit = 'Apple'
```

Query #2:

```
select a.*, b.quantity 
from fruits a 
left join fruitSales b on a.fruitPrice like '%' + b.fruitPrice + '%' 
where a.fruit = 'Orange'
```

In short: the only difference in my query is "like" in query2 and "=" in query1. I don't know how to use CASE queries in this case.(as my input data is dependent on two values, Apple or Banana)

Solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why dont u try if else then case statement in where as if else treat better in some scenarios by the optimizer.
if (@fruit ='Apple' )
then begin your query ........ end
if (@fruit ='Banana' )
then begin your query ........ end

Comment: Can I do that for two inputs? if(@fruit =Apple OR @fruit=Banana) ? Does something like this exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` condition in `JOIN` condition.

```
 select a.*, b.quantity 
 from fruits a 
 left join fruitSales b on 
   CASE WHEN a.fruit IN ('Apple', 'Banana') 
                  AND a.fruitPrice = '%'+b.fruitPrice+'%' 
        THEN 1
        WHEN a.fruit NOT IN ('Apple', 'Banana')  
                 AND a.fruitPrice like '%' + b.fruitPrice + '%' 
        THEN 1
        ELSE  0
    END = 1
 where a.fruit = 'Apple'
```

Comment: this worked..thank you Kumar:)
@All..thanks for your replies...I will also try and learn the other replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.quantity 
FROM fruits a 
LEFT JOIN fruitSales b ON a.fruitPrice LIKE (CASE WHEN a.fruit IN ('Apple', 'Banana') THEN b.fruitPrice ELSE CONCAT('%', b.fruitPrice, '%') END)
WHERE a.fruit = 'Apple';
```

Comment: nope I mean my requirement is to filter based on LIKE or =. Even if(fruit=Apple or banana) the result should be CONCAT('%', b.fruitPrice, '%'). but with =

Comment: @CoolGurl Can you clarify with data that you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @fruit varchar(50)
SET @fruit = '' -- your value
IF @fruit ='apple' OR @fruit = 'banana'
BEGIN
    SELECT a.*, b.quantity 
    FROM fruits a 
    LEFT JOIN fruitSales b ON a.fruitPrice LIKE '%'+b.fruitPrice+'%' 
    WHERE a.fruit = 'Apple' 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT a.*, b.quantity 
    FROM fruits a 
    LEFT JOIN fruitSales b ON a.fruitPrice LIKE '%' + b.fruitPrice + '%' 
    WHERE a.fruit = 'Orange'
END
```

Comment: Should I go with store procedures for such requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

but why do you need a case query?

```
 select a.*, b.quantity 
 from fruits a 
 left join fruitSales b on 
    (a.fruit in ( 'Apple', 'Banana') and a.fruitPrice = '%'+b.fruitPrice+'%')
    or
    (a.fruit not in ( 'Apple', 'Banana') and a.fruitPrice like '%'+b.fruitPrice+'%')
 where a.fruit = <your fruit>
```

Comment: Ya I dont really need case. I want to solve it in a simple way. But your query doesn't work for my requirement.